# Maximize a window programmatically and prevent the user from changing the windows state

Tags: c#, .net-2.0

How do I maximize a window programmatically so that it cannot be resized once it 
reaches the maximized state (for example, maximize Internet Explorer and see it)?

I set FormWindowState property as

```
this.WindowState = FormWindowState.Maximized;
this.MaximizedBounds = (x,y);
```

but it doesn't work. How do I do this?

The window I want to maximize is a window in my application.

Comment: Is it a window in your application or some other program's window you want to maximize?

Answer (score 44):

When your form is maximized, set its minimum size = max size, so user cannot resize it.

```
    this.WindowState = FormWindowState.Maximized;
    this.MinimumSize = this.Size;
    this.MaximumSize = this.Size;
```

Answer (score 7):

You were close... after your code of

```
WindowState = FormWindowState.Maximized;
```

THEN, set the form's min/max size capacity to the value once its sized out.

```
MinimumSize = this.Size;
MaximumSize = this.Size;
```

Comment: you can simple write as well `MinimumSize = MaximumSize = this.Size;`

Comment: @balexandre, yes, but at his reputation at 58, I didn't want to possibly confuse the person with how multiple assignments can work in a single stream of variables.

Comment: Didn't work here. Instead, MinimumSize = MaximumSize was the answer.

Answer (score 2):

To stop the window being resizeable once you've maximised it you need to change the `FormBorderStyle` from `Sizable` to  one of the fixed constants:

```
FixedSingle
Fixed3D
FixedDialog
```

From the [MSDN Page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.formborderstyle.aspx) Remarks section:

> The border style of the form determines how the outer edge of the form appears. In addition to changing the border display for a form, certain border styles prevent the form from being sized. For example, the FormBorderStyle.FixedDialog border style changes the border of the form to that of a dialog box and prevents the form from being resized. The border style can also affect the size or availability of the caption bar section of a form.

It will change the appearance of the form if you pick `Fixed3D` for example, and you'll probably have to do some work if you want the form to restore to non-maximised and be resizeable again.

Answer (score 0):

To programmatically maximize the windowstate you can use:

```
 this.WindowState = FormWindowState.Maximized;
 this.MaximizeBox = false;
```

Comment: what you used is formawindowstate what is this your form name ?

Answer (score 0):

Change the property `WindowState` to `System.Windows.Forms.FormWindowState.Maximized`, in some cases if the older answers doesn't works.

So the window will be maximized, and the other parts are in the other answers.